# intellisense not working for personal component library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, intellisense

I created a React component library with typescript and published on npm.

I can use it in other project and so on but when i want to autoimport the Button or any other component, the intellisense does not show me component beeing available.

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "ESNext",
    "target": "ES5",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "lib": ["dom", "esnext"],
    "declaration": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "linktech-test-react",
  "version": "1.0.4",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf dist",
    "prebuild": "npm run clean",
    "build": "tsc",
    "preversion": "npm run build",
    "postversion": "git push --follow-tags"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^29.2.2",
    "@types/node": "^18.11.9",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.25",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.8",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.6.2"
  }
}
```

src/index.tsx

```
export { default as Button } from "./Button";
export * from "./Button";

export { default as Alert } from "./Alert";
export * from "./Alert";
```

src/Button/Button.tsx

```
import React, { HTMLAttributes, ReactNode } from "react";

export type ButtonProps = {
  children: ReactNode;
  variant: "priamry" | "secondary";
};
/**
 * This is a button component
 *
 * @param {ReactNode} children - The content of the button
 * @param {string} variant - The variant of the button
 *
 */
const Button = ({ children, ...props }: ButtonProps) => {
  return <button {...props}>{children}</button>;
};

export default Button;
```

src/Button/index.ts

```
export { default } from "./Button";
export * from "./Button";
```

desired output:

[image]

Actual output:
[image]

Folder structure:
[image]

Dist is the build folder

dist/Button/Button.d.ts

```
import { ReactNode } from "react";
export declare type ButtonProps = {
    children: ReactNode;
    variant: "priamry" | "secondary";
};
/**
 * This is a button component
 *
 * @param {ReactNode} children - The content of the button
 * @param {string} variant - The variant of the button
 *
 */
declare const Button: ({ children, ...props }: ButtonProps) => JSX.Element;
export default Button;
```

dist/Button/Button.js

```
var __assign = (this && this.__assign) || function () {
    __assign = Object.assign || function(t) {
        for (var s, i = 1, n = arguments.length; i < n; i++) {
            s = arguments[i];
            for (var p in s) if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(s, p))
                t[p] = s[p];
        }
        return t;
    };
    return __assign.apply(this, arguments);
};
var __rest = (this && this.__rest) || function (s, e) {
    var t = {};
    for (var p in s) if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(s, p) && e.indexOf(p) < 0)
        t[p] = s[p];
    if (s != null && typeof Object.getOwnPropertySymbols === "function")
        for (var i = 0, p = Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(s); i < p.length; i++) {
            if (e.indexOf(p[i]) < 0 && Object.prototype.propertyIsEnumerable.call(s, p[i]))
                t[p[i]] = s[p[i]];
        }
    return t;
};
import { jsx as _jsx } from "react/jsx-runtime";
/**
 * This is a button component
 *
 * @param {ReactNode} children - The content of the button
 * @param {string} variant - The variant of the button
 *
 */
var Button = function (_a) {
    var children = _a.children, props = __rest(_a, ["children"]);
    return _jsx("button", __assign({}, props, { children: children }));
};
export default Button;
```

dist/Button/index.d.ts and index.js

```
export { default } from "./Button";
export * from "./Button";
```

dist/index.d.ts and index.js

```
export { default as Button } from "./Button";
export * from "./Button";
export { default as Alert } from "./Alert";
export * from "./Alert";
```

I already tried to search eveyrthing was possible about this but i could not find any viable solution

Comment: can you share your GitHub repo link?

Comment: https://github.com/andreimihale/linktech-ui